# How to assign JSON to a class recursively?

Tags: javascript, json, recursion

To modelize a family structure, I used the simple `Person` class, and I would be able to save a structure as text, and later go in the other way. But my class has different methods useful and indispensable to my code, I found the way for the first object, but how to continue in depth?

*Depth here is 1, but it can go up to 6*

```js
let json = {"name":"SON","date":"2000-01-01T05:00:00.000Z","sex":"H",
            "dad":{"name":"DAD","date":"2000-01-02T05:00:00.000Z","sex":"H","dad":null,"mom":null},
            "mom":{"name":"MOM","date":"2000-01-03T05:00:00.000Z","sex":"F","dad":null,"mom":null}
           };

class Person {
    constructor(name, date, sexe) {
        this.name = name;
        this.date = date;
        this.sexe = sexe;
        this.dad = null;
        this.mom = null;
    }
    doStuff(){
      console.log(this.name);
    }
}

let obj =  Object.assign(new Person,json);

//OK
obj.doStuff();     

//NOK 'obj.dad.doStuff is not a function' as 'dad' is not associated to Person
obj.dad.doStuff();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it recursively, calling the same function that performs `Object.assign` on `dad` and `mom` if they are not `null`:

```js
let json = {
  "name": "SON", "date": "2000-01-01","sex": "H",
  "dad": {
    "name": "DAD","date": "2000-01-02","sex": "H", "dad": null,"mom": null
  },
  "mom": {
    "name": "MOM","date": "2000-01-03","sex": "F","dad": null,
    "mom" : { "name": "GRAMDA","date": "2000-01-02","sex": "F","dad": null,"mom": null }
  }
};

class Person {
  constructor(name, date, sexe) {
    this.name = name;
    this.date = date;
    this.sexe = sexe;
    this.dad = null;
    this.mom = null;
  }
  doStuff() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
}

function buildPersons(root) {
  let obj = Object.assign(new Person, root);
  if (obj.dad) obj.dad = buildPersons(obj.dad);
  if (obj.mom) obj.mom = buildPersons(obj.mom);
  return obj;
}

let obj = buildPersons(json);
obj.doStuff();
obj.dad.doStuff();
obj.mom.mom.doStuff();
```